# Phonegap navigator.app.exitApp() return back to previous page rather than exit

Tags: cordova, navigation

Using Phonegap 3.4.

Phonegap `navigator.app.exitApp()` not working occasionally. 
I have try but not works,
It would return to previous page rather than exit.
It does work sometimes but not all the time.

Is it due to some cache or history settings? What is the workflow behind 
`navigator.app.exitApp()`?